# Is the dependency jar should be executable?

Tags: jar, jetty, executable-jar

I am developing 2 different web applications. I have packed common functionalities in a `executable jar`. Im using Jetty V9.2. I have placed the dependency jar in `'jetty-base\lib\ext'`. This loads the jar on start up. I have noticed that the jar is not loaded if it is not a executable one. Hence I modifed the jar as executable one and it works fine. Is this way the jars should be used? All libraries of the server are executable jars? I am not familiar with jar usage.

Answer (score 0):

Both `non-executable JAR` and `Executable JAR` works fine. It was a mistake that I dint include the dependencies while exporting a `non-executable JAR`. I placed all required libraries in `lib\ext`. It works!